# How to use docker to connect with jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I try to connect to jupyter notebooks from macos terminal, but when I use

```
python run_docker_jupyter.py
```

it returns me

```
Projects/data_science_course/mlcourse_open:/notebooks -w /notebooks festline/mlcourse_open jupyter
Command: jupyter
[I 14:12:55.078 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 14:12:55.101 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[W 14:12:55.101 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
[I 14:12:55.113 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
[I 14:12:55.114 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 14:12:55.114 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:4545/
[I 14:12:55.114 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

And I need to connect with local host, but after some command it returns me nothing. Or if I use `docker ps` or another docker command, it only prints this command in the terminal with sign `[` before the command and after that it turn to next string. And that's all.

It's the first time I use docker, so I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use test your python first, e.t. try to run something as simple as:

```
python -c "print('test')"
```

you should have you "test" string as output.

Then try to check your docker:
issue:

```
$docker-machine ssh
```

if everything is okay you will be able to run

```
$docker ls
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with kernel crashes that can be fixed by using Tini, I have attached links to a couple of gists that work very well.

[Docker-compose yaml](https://gist.github.com/gdahlm/53527df714d5a9916161fe25ca7a5a90) and [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/gdahlm/dc4c08da8e97e10057c3136c93bdaf69)